# Where is the source code for the python 'dict' type?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to view the source code of the python `dict` type but i can't find it.

I'm looking for python 2.6.

Comment: Check http://www.laurentluce.com/?p=249 for a walk-through the implementation.

Comment: dictnotes.txt in the source (adjacent to the C source file linked in the answers) is also potentially useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is latest python2.6.6 dictobject source code from python svn

> http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/tags/r266/Objects/dictobject.c?revision=84293&content-type=text/plain

Comment: FYI for those looking for newer source, this link is broken as of 12/8 as Python source has moved to github as pointed out by [@Delgan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728790/7954504)

Answer (score 20):

Now that Python migrated to Github, here is the updated link:

[`cpython/Objects/dictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more recent link with source highlighting: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c

Answer (score 4):

Look at `Objects/dictobject.c` in the Python source code.