# What is the difference between data type and data structure?

Tags: python, data-structures, types

I found out this question has been answered before, but not very clear to me.
I understand data type can somehow called user defined class actually it is same as class in python.

But in some books dictionary (dict) is called data structure some books call it data type.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary (or map or associative-array) is a data-structure with keys and values.

In Python, that data structure can be used [as the `dict` datatype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html?highlight=dict)

---

So, to answer the question more broadly, all languages have built-in data types.

Not all languages have built-in data structures, but they generally can be implemented by using the data types that are available

> Can we construct a class for specific data structure?

Sure, for example, I would make a `class LinkedList` or `class BinaryTree`, but as mentioned, those are composed of more simpler types.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I take it in this why: if it is a build in data structure it is called data type, if it is user construct type it is called data structure? Then shouldn’t user construct class called data type as well?

Comment: Can we construct a class for specific data structure? But if we can then shouldn’t it be a data type?

Comment: A class is a data-type in OOP languages. Not all languages have classes.

Comment: dict is written in C, though, not as a Python class. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728790/2308683

Comment: May I ask the difference of data type or data structure is judged by their complexity? Or there is normally not much difference?

Comment: That question doesn't really make sense to me. Even complex data structures can be explained using operations of simpler data types. More operations makes it complex, I guess?

Comment: Thank you. Or can I say data structure is a structure to organising different data types make them easy to be operate and work efficiently?

Comment: That is the definition of a data structure. Just because something is complex, doesn't mean it is inefficient, though

Answer (score 1):

Data structure is a general computer science concept. It is just a way of organizing data to make certain operations easier or harder.

Data type is a concept specific to a programming language. In a way, it is a concrete implementation of a data structure in a particular programming language. But the actual definition of what constitutes a "type" varies among programming languages. For example, in `C`, you can define a `struct` and use it as a type. There are also basic types like `int`, `float`, `char` etc. In `python`, you can use the built-in types like `list`, `set` etc. or define your own types using classes.

Comment: So we can call some user define data type -data structure if it is complicated structured?

Comment: It doesn't need to be complicated. Even simple types are data structures. Even a simple `int` (talking in `C` terms) can be thought of as a data structure.

Comment: Thanks. So sounds like there is no major difference between data type and date structure even in python terms right